# Variadic template where we want to automate the creation of operator@ where it exists for each template variable

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++14, variadic-templates

Suppose that we have a template like below, but we would prefer that it be variadic and we can automate the creation of the various operators that should be implemented - How do we approach this?

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
class Foo { 
private:
    boost::variant<T1, T2, T3, T4> var_;
public:
    Foo(const T1& t1) : var_(t1) { }
    Foo(const T2& t2) : var_(t2) { }
    Foo(const T3& t3) : var_(t3) { }
    Foo(const T4& t4) : var_(t4) { }

    Foo operator@(const T1& t1) const { return t1 @ boost::get<T1>(var_);}
    Foo operator@(const T2& t2) const { return t2 @ boost::get<T2>(var_);}
    Foo operator@(const T3& t3) const { return t3 @ boost::get<T3>(var_);}
    Foo operator@(const T4& t4) const { return t4 @ boost::get<T4>(var_);}
    Foo operator@(const Foo& foo) const
    {
        switch (foo.which())
        {
         case 0: return *this @ boost::get<T1>(foo.var_);
         case 1: return *this @ boost::get<T2>(foo.var_);
         case 2: return *this @ boost::get<T3>(foo.var_);
         case 3: return *this @ boost::get<T4>(foo.var_);
         }
     }
};

int main()
{
    T1 t11, t12;
    Foo<T1, T2, T3, T4> foo1(t11), foo2(t12);
    Foo<T1, T2, T3, T4> foo = foo1 @ foo2;
    Foo<T1, T2, T3, T4> foo11 = t11 @ foo2;
    Foo<T1, T2, T3, T4> foo12 = foo1 @ t12;
    // assuming we have implemented operator==, I would expect that
    // foo, f11, f12 were all equal here.

    return 0;
}
```

I'm leaving out some type checking and other things for brevity.  Hopefully, the point is clear.

Using `std::enable_if_t`, I'm sure we can figure out how to know when `operator@` should be implemented for each `T_i`.  However, is there a clever way to use variadic templates to create such a class and have all the operators I want overloaded in the canonical way?  I don't specifically need to do this really as there is only one version of such a variadic template that I would use 99.9% of the time, but I think it is an interesting question.

Comment: So just to clarify. You want `template <typename... Args> Foo` with the operators generated for each `A` in `Args`?

Comment: pretty much - I am curious if that can be done.  The operators should only be generated for each A that supports the operator.  If the oeprator is not supported, don't do it of course.

Comment: What should happens if it doesn't exist ?

Comment: If it doesn't exist, the operator should not be created.  Let's consider that a secondaray problem - happy to see a clean solution where we assume that the operator exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll solve this for `+` and `+=`.

```
template<class D, std::size_t I, class T>
struct plus_helper {
  D& operator+=( T const& rhs ) & {
    using boost::get;
    get<I>(self()) += rhs;
    return self();
  }

  friend T operator+( plus_helper<D,I,T>&& self, T const& rhs ) {
    using boost::get;
    return get<I>(std::move(self.self())) + rhs;
  }

  friend T operator+( plus_helper<D,I,T>const& self, T const& rhs ) {
    using boost::get;
    return get<I>(self.self()) + rhs;
  }

private:
  D const& self() const { return *static_cast<D const*>(this); }
  D & self() { return *static_cast<D*>(this); }
};


template<class D, class Indexes, class...Ts>
struct plus_helpers;

template<class D, std::size_t...Is, class...Ts>
struct plus_helpers<D, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...> : plus_helper<D, Is, Ts>...
{
  template<typename T>
  T& get() {return boost::get<T>(self().var_);}
  template<typename T>
  const T& get() const {return boost::get<T>(self().var_);}

  using own_type = plus_helpers<D, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>;
  //using plus_helper<D,Is,Ts>::operator+...;
  using plus_helper<D,Is,Ts>::operator+=...;

  D& operator+=( D const& rhs )& {
    using fptr = void(*)( D& lhs, D const& rhs );

    // dispatch table: (or use boost::visit)
    static constexpr fptr table[] = {
      (+[]( D& lhs, D const& rhs ) {
        using boost::get;
        lhs += get<Is>(rhs);
      })...
    };

    table[rhs.which()]( self(), rhs );

    return self();
  }

  friend D operator+(own_type&& lhs, D const& rhs ) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return std::move(lhs.self());
  }

  friend D operator+(own_type const& lhs, D const& rhs ) {
    auto tmp = lhs.self();
    return std::move(tmp)+rhs;
  }

private:
  D& self() { return *static_cast<D*>(this); }
  D const& self() const { return *static_cast<D const*>(this); }
};
```

this uses one bit of [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) -- the `using /*[...]*/::operator+...;`.  To do this in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) you need to build a tree (possibly a linear tree) of `plus_helper` and binary `using operator+` at each bud.

You are likely to have similar code for each operator; but not identical.  `+` and `==` are not the same because you want to support `+=` but not `===`.  ;)

You'll probably want a few macros that spew out most of the above boilerplate.

In the final class we do:

```
template<class...Ts>
class Foo:
 public plus_helpers<Foo<Ts...>, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>, Ts...>
{
  boost::variant<Ts...> var_;
public:
  template<std::size_t I>
  friend decltype(auto) get( Foo<Ts...> const& foo ) {
    using boost::get;
    return get<std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Ts...>>>(foo.var_);
  }
  template<std::size_t I>
  friend decltype(auto) get( Foo<Ts...> & foo ) {
    using boost::get;
    return get<std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Ts...>>>(foo.var_);
  }
};
```

You can add type-based get:

```
template<class T>
friend decltype(auto) get( Foo<Ts...> & foo ) {
    using boost::get;
    return get<T>(foo.var_);
}
template<class T>
friend decltype(auto) get( Foo<Ts...>const & foo ) {
    using boost::get;
    return get<T>(foo.var_);
}
```

as well.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73a50b4e418195dd).

---

A naive [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) inheritance/using replacement:

```
template<class...Bases>
struct inherit_plus_operations {}; // empty
template<class Lhs, class...Rhs>
struct inherit_plus_operations<Lhs, Rhs...>:
  Lhs,
  inherit_plus_operations<Rhs...>
{
  //using Lhs::operator+;
  //using inherit_plus_operations<Rhs...>::operator+;
  using Lhs::operator+=;
  using inherit_plus_operations<Rhs...>::operator+=;
};
template<class Lhs> // one
struct inherit_plus_operations<Lhs>:
  Lhs
{
  //using Lhs::operator+;
  using Lhs::operator+=;
};

template<class D, std::size_t...Is>, class...Ts>
struct plus_helpers<D, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>:
  inherit_plus_operations<plus_helper<D, Is, Ts>...>
```

then get rid of `using /* ... */::operator+/*...*/...;` from body.

Comment: Interesting - I'll need some time to parse this - thx for the reply.  It is the math operators that I am most interested in.  This ultimate class should be one that occupies the cells of a theoretical C++ data frame class that behaves like python's pandas

Comment: @FinanceGuyThatCantCode Added some `#if`/`#else` alternative implementations that are simpler and should work as well.

Comment: I have just tried to toy with this on Coliru - I admit that I truly don't know how to code, but have some ideas on what you are doing....however, I cannot get a toy example to work.  I did have to remove a couple small bugs from your code like an incorrect const qualified member function and a reference qualified function for the friend functions etc.).  I also added get() and which() functions to apply to the variant.  See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c3651f145580f4e

Comment: @FinanceGuyThatCantCode Ah, two problems.  One, boost get is only by type.  I'm used to std variant, which has a get by index.  A second problem is we didn't publish get on `Foo`.  One sec.

Comment: @FinanceGuyThatCantCode Fixed

Comment: This is brilliant.  I am definitely a rookie on a lot of this template witchcraft, but I definitely also learned something here.  As a quant, I often lack the time to learn top notch programming, but I do appreciate it!  Next I’ll add a null type to the 0-index Arg through boost::blank or something.  Adding incompatible types should result in null I suppose.  For DataFrames, null/nan is critical of course.

Comment: I will also try to get operator T() as well, so things like Foo<int, double> foo(2); int x = foo; work.  That works in my poor persons version from the original question.  I know those sorts of operators scare people, but it is important to reduce the verbosity of my codebase.

Comment: @finan use SFINAE on a template operator conversion.  `template<class T, std::enable_if_t< /* expr */, bool> =true> operator T()const{ return boost::get<T>(var_); }` --- `expr` being something like `(std::is_same_v<T,Ts>||...)` in C++17

Answer (score 3):

If you can get rid of "optimized" version with direct `T1`, `T4`, you might simply use `boost::apply_visitor`(/`std::visit` in C++17 with `std::variant`) :

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Foo { 
private:
    boost::variant<Ts...> var_;
public:
    // ...

    friend decltype(auto) operator@(const Foo& lhs_foo, const Foo& rhs_foo)
    {
        return boost::apply_visitor([](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs) { return lhs @ rhs; },
                                    lhs_foo.var_,
                                    rhs_foo.var_);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach to keep the amount of boilerplate as small as possible is to allow the implicit construction of `Foo` instances. This way, you don't even have to write any operator overload for a type other than `Foo`. As an example, consider the following template.

```
template <typename ...Args> class Foo { 
    public:
        // Evil shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-catch-all ctor:
        template <class T> Foo(T&& t) : var(std::forward<T>(t)) {}

        friend bool operator == (const Foo<Args...>& lhs, const Foo<Args...>& rhs)
        {
            return lhs.var == rhs.var;
        }

    private:
        std::variant<Args...> var;
};
```

It allows any argument that can be used to construct the data member `var` to implicitly instantiate a `Foo` instance suitable for the `operator ==`.

```
Foo<int, double, std::string> f1(42);
Foo<int, double, std::string> f2(43);

assert(f1 == f1);
assert(!(f1 == f2));

assert(42 == f1);
assert(!(f1 == 1.2345));
assert(!(f1 == "hello"));
```

Comment: Let's assume that we want operator+ and that var includes a type to represent null and that adding incompatible types should set the var to the null object.  Does this approach work?  Also - why is that catch-all constructor evil?

Comment: That catch all constructor has exact match for `Foo(Foo&)` (so better than default copy constructor).

Comment: No this doesn't work, in `lhs.var == rhs.var` the actual comparison is delegated to the `std::variant` implementation. But you could check for the current type of lhs and rhs inside the operator implementation and handle special cases based upon that.